# uploadify file object structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

Can anyone tell me the structure of the uploadify file object (used by methods such as onSelect and onUploadSuccess). I have scoured the official documentation but with little success; although I know I can access `file.name` from the documentation (and after a bit of trial and error I know I can also get `file.size`), I have no idea what other properties I can get my hands on.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Many thanks.

Comment: You can do `console.log(file)` in your `onUploadSuccess` and find out all the properties of `file` object yourself.

Comment: That did it! Can't believe I forgot Firebug! Cheers :)

Comment: @Joy put this down as an answer and I'll mark you as correct.

Comment: Just posted an answer. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `console.log(file)` in your `onUploadSuccess` and find out all the properties of file object yourself in `console`.